# whats the difference for indexing of signed and unsigned char in array?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have to following code, which doesn't generate my expected results. Adding unsigned char would make it work. ( I realized it is not working by having another function doing the reverse, but not getting the reverse effect!)
Can someone explain a bit to me.

The code is to substitute a 8 char string to some random chars.

My current code :

```
char subs[8][256];

void perfSubs(char* input){
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    input[i] = subs[i][input[i]];
}
```

I should change it to

```
input[i] = subs[i][(unsigned char)input[i]];
```

Comment: You can't have a negative array index.  (Has nothing to do with indexing a signed vs unsigned array, but rather with using a signed vs unsigned value as an index.)

Comment: @HotLicks: this is wrong, you can use negative indices.

Comment: @doukremt - Not (legally) on a vanilla array, where the array pointer is addressing the first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by others and is well known that C has `unsigned char`, `signed char` and `char` types.
`char` has the same range as either `unsigned char`, `signed char` but is still a different type.

`subs[i][input[i]];` may involve a negative index into `subs[i][some_negative_value]` casuing the problem.

`input[i] = subs[i][(unsigned char)input[i]];` folds the negative values into positive ones that may come out of `input[i]`, but that is implementation defined behavior as to how.

A simple solution can be had just using `char`.

---

To avoid a negative index, subtract the minimum `char` value, `CHAR_MIN`, whenever code uses `char` as an index.  A typical value for `CHAR_MIN` is 0 or -128.

Also avoid the magic number 256 and use an array size based on `char`.

```
char subs[8][CHAR_MAX + 1 - CHAR_MIN];

input[i] = subs[i][input[i] - CHAR_MIN];
```

Depending on if `char` is signed or not, the location of using index `'A'` may result in a different index, though consistent within a given compilation.

```
subs[0]['A' - CHAR_MIN] = 'x';
```

Comment: This method and OP's method (i.e. `char subs[8][UCHAR_MAX];   subs[i][(unsigned char)input[i]] = 'x';`) are both valid.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Minor: Certainly you meant `subs[8][UCHAR_MAX+1];`.  I would agree as to the general equivalence about the 2 methods.  Many other like problems where some an array with signed values, then applied as an index, can use the `- VALUE_IN_ARRAY_MIN` approach without resorting to type changes.  A good compiler may readily compile the offset such that there is no performance impact either.

Answer (score 1):

The standard does not dictate whether `char` is a signed type or an unsigned type. It can be signed type in one platform and unsigned type in another platform. If you want your code to be portable, pick a type that you can depend on.

In your case, you should use:

```
void perfSubs(unsigned char* input){
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    input[i] = subs[i][input[i]];
}
```

This makes sure that you get an `unsigned char*` to the function and not have to rely on whether the `char` type is a signed type or an unsigned type.

Answer (score 0):

A signed char can hold values from -128 to 127. Since you're using the byte to store values from 0 to 255, you need an unsigned char.

Comment: I didn't think C restricted `char` to 8 bits (not my downvote BTW.)

Comment: @juanchopanza C restricts it to `CHAR_BIT`. Posix and windows requires that `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Comment: @sharth Exactly, so this answer is making assumptions.

Comment: The relevant thing is that negative values are permitted, not the magnitude of the values.